# separate characters concatenated with + in R

Tags: r

I have a factor vector that looks like this:

```
[1] A
[2] B+C
[3] A+D+E
[4] F
...
```

I would like to have a vector of items that is separated by the "+" sign, i.e. in the example above, I want to have a vector `A B C D E F`. The "+" signs are removed and duplicate of items are also removed. How can I do that in R? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should split the vector using `strsplit` at `+` (by escaping it). Then, you'll get a list where each element of the vector is split at `+`. Then you can `unlist` it to get back the vector. From there you can call `unique` to remove duplicates.

```
x <- c("A", "B+C", "B+D", "A+D+E", "F", "F+C")
unique(unlist(strsplit(x, "\\+")))
# [1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F"
```

Answer (score 5):

Another option using `scan` and you get a vector of letters from which you remove duplicated using `unique`:

```
unique(scan(text='A
B+C
A+D+E
F',what='character',sep='+'))
Read 7 items
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F"
```